# TikZ library `external` doesn't recognize node name from different picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external

I am attempting to improve my compilation time by externalizing Ti*k*Z pictures. I do seem to be able to refer to named nodes, however. For example, consider the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\tikz \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\tikz \coordinate [right=of A] (B);

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this with `pdflatex -shell-escape presention.tex`, I get the message

```
===== Image 'presentation-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "presentation-figure1" "\def\tikzextern
alrealjob{presentation}\input{presentation}"' ========
\openout3 = `presentation.auxlock'.

runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname
 "presentation-figure1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{presentation}\input{presentat
ion}")...executed.

\openout3 = `presentation.auxlock'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "presentation-figure1" "\def\tikzexternalr
ealjob{presentation}\input{presentation}"' did NOT result in a usable output fi
le 'presentation-figure1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verif
y that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-es
cape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe t
he command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'presentation-figure1.
log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

in `presentation.log` and the message

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14     \tikz \coordinate [right=of A] (B);
```

in `presentation-figure1.log`. I have tried to refer to the manual and the internet to figure out what the problem is, but I have had no luck. I know that the `external` package can't handle references easily, but I can't find anything about named nodes.

Note that the named nodes are declared in different Ti*k*Z pictures because, in my real code, I refer to them throughout my document, in many different pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't with "known" technology.  To do this properly, you'd need to save the coordinate positions to a file and read them back in at the start of the compilation.

However, if the coordinates are all defined in a few simple pictures at the start of the document, simply turn off externalisation for those pictures and then the coordinates will be available for all later pictures whether externalised or not.

The following compiles with no errors and the second picture is externalised:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296865/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/export next=false}
\tikz \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\tikz \coordinate [right=of A] (B);

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the environment `tikzpicture` if you want to externalize Ti*k*Z graphics and refer to existing node/coordinate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
Hi
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [right=of A] (B);
\draw (A)--(B)--+(45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Externalized image]

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm getting the same errors. Note that it is necessary to use the nodes in several pictures, which is why they're not defined in the same picture.

Comment: The code above works for me, and the image attached is the externalized output. If you want to refer to a node defined in another picture you should include this (very) important detail in your question! As far as I know you cannot do that with the externalization, so I suggest you to turn off the 'externalize' engine for those figures that refer to nodes defined elsewhere.

Comment: The code you posted also works for me, just not when the declarations are split. My question has been modified to clarify my intent.

Comment: Ok, I'm not able to do that, it may not be possible at all. Try to compile with Lualatex or disable the externalize engine when you call to outside nodes.